# How to have window size itself to longest string

Tags: wpf, window, size

I am adding a new window to my application.  This application contains a `ListBox` whose `ItemsSource` property is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of view model objects.  Here is the data template used to render the view model objects:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DomainTemplate" DataType="DomainViewModel">
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}, Path=IsSelected}"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Margin="5"
            Name="SelectedBorder">
        <Button Click="SelectDomain_Click"
                Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                FontSize="16"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Height="60"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CurrentSiteIsValid, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type c:DomainPicker}}}"
                Margin="5" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am using the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` setting on the `ListBox` to make all of the `Buttons` fill the width of the `ListBox`.  Also, the view model objects are read from a database, and the Name property can have any string up to 80 characters long in it.

The problem is that I want the width of the `Buttons` to be the same as the width of the `Button` with the longest caption would be if it were directly on the window.  Then the `ListBox` should size itself to contain that `Button`, and finally the window should size itself to the `ListBox`.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Your last paragraph is a little unclear.  can you maybe post a screenshot of what result you have now, and how you want to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `Button` controls to be the same length, you could add a `Grid` with the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` property set to `true` into your `DataTemplate`. Define one column with the `SharedSizeGroup` property set:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DomainTemplate" DataType="DomainViewModel">
    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Button" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}, 
Path=IsSelected}" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" Name="SelectedBorder">
            <Button Click="SelectDomain_Click" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" 
FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Height="60" IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentSiteIsValid, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type c:DomainPicker}}}" Margin="5" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

To get the `Button` controls to stop filling the `ListBox`, remove the `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` declaration from it.

To make the `Window` size fit the content, set its `SizeToContent` property to `WidthAndHeight` and remove all `Width` and `Height` properties from its declaration.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Your code is almost right.  I played with it a bit and found that the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` attached property must go on the `ListBox`, not the `Grid` in the `DataTemplate`.  Everything else is the same.  The only other problem I have with it is that the width of the `ListBox` is bigger than the width of the `Buttons`.  But that's because the title makes the window too wide

Comment: Put the `ListBox` into a `Grid` column that has its width set to `Auto`?

Comment: The `ListBox` is in a grid, but its width was not set to `Auto`.  It is now.  I also left the title empty & put a `TextBlock` bound to the title at the top, under the title bar.  This window is an app bar window for the application, so it will only be displayed when the application is running.